# Weird function calling convention

Tags: c++, hook, windbg

I'm debugging a x86 DLL in windbg, in particular a function that supposedly has the following signature:

```
bool __cdecl func(LPVOID p1, LPVOID p2, wchar_t* p3, size_t p4, LPVOID p5)
```

The function is not exported. AFAIK `__cdecl` should receive all the arguments on the stack and the **caller** should clear the stack.

But it's not what happens. Windbg says the calling convention is `__cdecl` but the first 2 arguments are passed on `ecx` and `edx`, just like a `__fastcall` function. Also the function itself is clearing the stack, what (i think) should not be done by a `__cdecl` function.

I'm trying to hook that function with no success. I tried to make a detour function as `__cdecl` and `__fastcall` and both cause a crash.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible that if the function is in an executable (not a library) or only called from within the same DLL, then the compiler can optimize the calling convention as it sees fit.

If the compiler knows both ends (caller and callee), and knows the function won't be exported to another unit (as it would be with a library), then it can be optimized any-which-way.

So:  Is the function part of a finished executable?  Do you have optimizations on?

I recommend turning optimizations off, and trying again.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention it's a DLL, but the function is not exported. Also I don't own the source code as it's a third party DLL. However I think your answer still applies.

Comment: Compilers can freely optimize any non-exported functions, in either an executable or a DLL. For example, a compiler could inline the function, replace some of its parameters with constants (e.g. if it determines that all call sites use the same values for some parameters), or rewrite the calling convention as noted here. This is particularly common for functions declared `static`.

Comment: VC calls this feature "Link Time Code Generation", see MSDN for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbf3tbeh.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Not necessarily related to LTCG. The function being static could be enough.